# Typescript: reaching a class without exporting it

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have these classes each in there own file :

// /my-folder/a.ts

```
class A { // ... }
```

// /my-folder/b.ts

```
class B { // ... }
```

// /my-folder/c.ts

```
class C {
   a = new A();
   b = new B();
}

export const createC = () => new C();
```

Is something like this possible in Typescript?

Comment: No, to be able to use classes in other files you must to export classes

Comment: But the moment I export, everyone can instantiate classes A and B. Is there no way of emulating package scope (like in Java) in TS?

Comment: Who is everyone ?

Comment: What you're doing is perfectly working though, you can use `createC` to instantiate `C`, you dont have to import `C`

Comment: this is more of a 'what if' question. What if I had to publish a lib at work and don't want anyone to instantiate A or B directly. Cramming every class, interface, etc into one file would be a solution.. :/

Comment: If you're publishing a lib - just don't re-export this classes from the lib index/main

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest splitting your code into modules-folders. Each folder has `index.ts` file that exports public classes outside. Classes that are not listed inside `index.ts` still can be imported but by direct link - typescript allows it.

But anyway this approach creates some structure and logic.

I've created small stackblitz for you https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-qtx6ft.

I hope it helps.

Comment: I was wondering if I could prevent anyone (including myself when writing client code) from instantiating some classes, but also split classes logically into separate files. It seems that it's not possible in TS (at least not yet).